# error: no member function declared in class

Tags: c++, class

I keep getting the following errors from my code:

(line 58) error: no 'std::string Person::Modify_Person(Person)' member function declared in class 'Person' In function 'int main()':

(line 113) error: 'Modify_Person' was not declared in this scope

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void PassByByValue(int num2){

  cout << "You are in PassByValue()" << endl;

  num2++;

}
class Person{
    int age;
    string name;
    int height;
    int weight;
public:

    Person(){

    }

    Person(string name){
        this->name=name;
    }

    string getName(){
    return this->name;
    }

    void setAge(int age){
    this->age=age;
    }


    void setName(string name){
    this->name=name;
    }

    void setHeight(int height){
    this->height=height;
    }

    void setWeight(int weight){
    this->weight=weight;
    }


    ~Person(){

    }

};



string Person::Modify_Person(Person example){

    example.getName()="Jessica";

    return example.getName();
}

void PassByRef(int& num3){

cout << "You are in PassByRef()" << endl;

num3=50;

cout << "inside PassByRef() pNum is: " <<num3<<endl;

}

int main()
{
   int num1;
   int* pNum;

    num1=3;
    *pNum=5;

    PassByByValue(num1);

    cout << "num1= " <<num1 <<endl;

    PassByRef(*pNum);

    cout << "outside PassByRef() in main() pNum is: " <<pNum<<endl;

    PassByByValue(*pNum);

    double* DblePtr;

    DblePtr= new double;

    *DblePtr=12.0;

    cout<< "DblePtr: "<< &DblePtr;

    delete[] DblePtr;

    cout<< "DblePtr: "<< &DblePtr;

    Person human;
    human.setName("Kate");
    human.setAge(27);
    human.setHeight(100);
    human.setWeight(100);

    Modify_Person(human);

    cout << "Modify_Person returns: " << Modify_Person(human) <<endl;

    cout << "name should be Jessica: " << human.getName() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should read up on scoping rules. This might be a good place to start: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

Comment: Compiler's dead right. Nowhere in `Person` is a `Modify_Person` method declared. Outside `Person`, yep. Right below it. Bit too late, sadly.

Comment: Thanks @TallChuck and @user4581301!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot declare a member function outside a class in C++. To fix this, add a corresponding member function declaration to your class:

```
class Person{
...
public:
string Modify_Person(Person);
};
```

Then your code will work. Also, a suggestion: don't define constructors and destructors if they are empty; allow the compiler to generate them for you. If you are intending to disable move constructors etc. by doing this, write `Person() = default;` to have the compiler generate a default implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The function

```
string Person::Modify_Person(Person example) {

   example.getName()="Jessica";

   return example.getName();
}
```

has the following problems.

1. Use of `string Person::Modify_Person(Person example) { ... }` to define a function is valid only of `Modify_Person` is declared as a member function of the class. Since, it is not, you just need a global function.

   ```
   string Modify_Person(Person example) {
   ...
   }
   ```
2. The function cannot modify the object in the calling functions since the argument gets passed by value. No matter what you do to `example`, the value of the object that was used to call the function remains unchanged in the calling function. If you want to see any changes made to `example` to be visible in the calling function, you need to accept the argument by reference.

   ```
   //                         |
   //                         v
   string Modify_Person(Person& example) {
   ...
   }
   ```
3. The line

   ```
   example.getName()="Jessica";
   ```

   in the function does not modify the name of `example`. It is equivalent to saying:

   ```
   string temp = example.getName();
   temp = "Jessica";
   ```

   Hence, the line below that returns the name of `example` will simply return the name of `example`, and not `"Jessica"`, which I believe is counter to your expectation.

   That line needs to be changed to:

   ```
   example.setName("Jessica");
   ```

Here's what the function should look like:

```
string Modify_Person(Person& example) {
   example.setName("Jessica");
   return example.getName();
}
```